# How to call stored procedures from html file

Tags: html, plsql

Is it possible to call stored procedures from html files.? Like when I click on button it should call plsql stored procedures.

Comment: Is this Oracle? (Implied by PL/SQL tag but just checking as a couple of Postgres answers have appeared.)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes it is Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

The most you could do with a button in HTML is trigger an HTTP request.

You would need an HTTP server to listen for that request, connect to Postgres, and trigger the stored procedure.

Comment: You have any examples for this

Comment: Step 1: Pick an HTTP server and server-side programming language. Step 2: Find a Postgres API for that language which supports calling stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to implement it in PHP, this guide would give you an step-by-step guide as for how the stored procedure is called using PHP.

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-php/call-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="package_name.procedure_name" method= "get">
    <input type = "submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is my code. I'm using oracle sql developer.  When I click on the button,  it is not executing procedures.
Is this a right way as I'm new to this